# Read files asynchronously in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to load two files and perform the same operation on them asynchronously. My code is working fine as I am able to load the files and perform the operations on them. However, I am writing the same function twice. Any ideas on how to make this asynchronous?

```
var arrayTest =  require('./data1.json');

arrayTest.data.forEach(function(str) {
  var newStr = str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(match) {
    return match.split('').reverse().join('');
  });
  console.log(newStr);
});


var arrayTest2 =  require('./data2.json');

arrayTest2.data.forEach(function(str) {
  var newStr = str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(match) {
    return match.split('').reverse().join('');
  });
  console.log(newStr);
});
```

Comment: Are you looking to cut down on repeated code or are you looking for asynchronicity? Those are two completely different things. The first of those is easy to accomplish – just give the function you pass to `forEach` a name like any other function and use it twice.

Comment: Hey @Ryan I am looking to make this asynchronous. Any suggestions?

Comment: making this action asynchronously won't bring you any effort.

Comment: Which part of it do you want async?  Reading the file?  Or do you want the processing of it to be async too?  Other answers here show you how to make the reading of the file async, but if you want the looping to be async so other code can run in parallel with your loop, then you will have to create a child process to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using node js `fs` module. In this case action will be executed every time callback is called from `readFile` (for each file).

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function readFilesAsync(files, action) {

  files.forEach(file => {
    // Use node fs to read files async
    fs.readFile(file, action);

  });

}

// Your custom function
function replaceString(err, str) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var newStr = str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(match) {
    return match.split('').reverse().join('');
  });
  console.log(newStr);
}

readFilesAsync(['./data1.json', './data2.json'], replaceString);
```

Comment: It's possible to execute the action and make data an array containing both files data. We should include Promises in that case. Tell me if you want me to add them.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. Where should I put the original function within the async function you provided? Is it in action? Replace the action with a callback?

Comment: You put as the second argument, when calling readFilesAsync, like `readFilesAsync(['file1', 'file2'], YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE)` Make sure that your original function receives 2 arguments, first is the error second the data (the file contents)

Answer (score 0):

I would change it to something like that. Handle async IO with promises, and use 1 function, to avoid code duplication.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const files_paths = ['./data1.js', './data2.js'];

Promise.all(files_paths.map((path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
            resolve(data.split(',').map((str) => {
                return str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, (match) => {
                    return match.split('').reverse().join('');
                });
            }));
        });
    });
})).then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To load the files asynchronously, you can use `fs.readFile()` and then manually parse them yourself with `JSON.parse()` replacing the synchronous `require()`.  So, here's a function to load your files asynchronously and then parse them into Javascript:

```
// returns a promise
loadJsonAsync(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Note, the file loading will be async.  The JSON parsing will be synchronous.

You could then use this in a function that does your processing:

```
function loadAndProcess(f) {
    return loadJsonAsync(f).then(arr => {
        for (let str of arr.data) {
            const newStr = str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(match) {
                return match.split('').reverse().join('');
            });
            console.log(newStr);
            // do something with newStr here
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });
}
```

You could then run two of them like this:

```
Promise.all([loadAndProcess("./data1.json"),loadAndProcess("./data2.json")]).then(data => {
    // both are done here
 }).catch(err => {
    // error here
 });
```

If you wanted both the synchronous code that does the JSON parsing and the replace loop to also be asynchronous, then you would have to move that code to a child process and then communicate the result back to the main process when done because there is no way in nodejs to make synchronous operations become asynchronous operations in the same process.

Answer (score -1):

```
const arrayTest = require('./data1.json');
const arrayTest2 = require('./data2.json');

doJob(arrayTest);
doJob(arrayTest2);

function doJob(arr) {
  arr.data.forEach(function(str) {
    const newStr = str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(match) {
      return match.split('').reverse().join('');
    });
    console.log(newStr);
  });
}
```

In case you would like to merge array before:

```
doJob(arrayTest.concat(arrayTest2);
```

**Update:**
As I've already told you before, in most cases such 'asynchronous' flow is useless. Asyncronous flow is not parallel flow.

The real profit, in case you have really big files, might come from using child processes. In case if it's so, you can gather more [knowledge here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Comment: Apparently, this is not what the OP is looking for.  They want their operation made to be asynchronous.

Comment: @jfriend00 most probably, OP will eventually find this code sample more useful. No sense in making his code asyncronous.